# Pandas read_fwf doesn't read the last digital each row

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing, read-fwf

I have a .rpt file that has two columns, like this:

> ```
>            A column            B column
>           990.E-03            -2.73654E-03
>          995.E-03            -2.75347E-03
>           1.                -2.76635E-03
> ```

And when I use pd.read_fwf to read the table, `df = pd.read_fwf('myfile.rpt', delimiter="   ")`
it neglect the last digit.

For example, the table in my .rpt file:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 990.E-03 | **-2.73654E-03** |
| 960.E-03 | -2.6323E-03 |

will be converted to this table in df:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 0.99 | **-2.73654** |
| 0.96 | -0.0026323 |

It seems that when the function will neglect of the second column when the that cell has more than 11 letters, and in my cases that digit the magnitude which is the most important.
Looking forward to your solution.

Comment: Please show the contents of the file as text, not a table, and post your code.

Comment: Please show the contents of your file. `read_fwf()` completely depends on proper formatting of the read data. Potentially the first entry in column B could be wider than all other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alternative, you can read your RPT file with [`read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html) or [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and define `sep='\s+'` as parameter.

```
# or df.read_csv
df.read_table('myfile.rpt', sep='\s+')
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I am wondering when I use read_fwf('myfile.rpt', sep='\s+') still return the same wrong thing as read_fwf('myfile.rpt').

Comment: I think `read_fwf` ignores the `sep` parameter because it uses a fixed width to delimit fields